# Prove that for a normalizable $\mathbb{C}^1$ function, $-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi^*(x) (\partial_x^2\psi(x)) dx \geq 0$

Tags: calculus, analysis

Prove that for a normalizable $\mathbb{C}^1$ function, $-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \psi^*(x) (\partial_x^2\psi(x)) dx \geq 0$ where $\psi^*(x)$ was the complex conjugate of $\psi(x)$.

This should be consistent with [Copenhagen interperatoin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_interpretation) from physics, and the fact that the kinetic energy was positive.

Comment: What have you tried? Any integration by parts?

Comment: @cmk not sure, it's a complex function but cauchy riemann equation doesn't work since it only dependent on one parameter. But the statement should work, as there was a theorem proven the classical limit was consistent. The fact was that I used the states formalism to prove the statement rather in functional analysis, and it was simply an operator manipulation.

Comment: Being complex-valued shouldn't matter if $x$ is real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate by parts, and assuming that the boundary terms vanish, you are left with
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left|\partial_x \psi \right|^2 \, dx \ge 0$$